# Fresh Debian 10 - no sound: pls help!

Tags: audio, pulseaudio, alsa

I decided I want to use Linux again and since my first distro was Debian, I came back to it but still consider myself a noob. I knew there are always problems when installing a new Distro, but this time it gets tiring. Kernel is 4.19.

I do not have any sound output. I am running a Soundblaster Z soundcard which is recognized in alsa and set as my default audio device. In alsamixer nothing is muted and turned up. Spotify and speaker-test display no results.

Pulseaudio, or pavucontrol shows that there is definitly an input because the output bar is moving.

`pacmd list-sinks` gives the following output:

```
1 sink(s) available.
  * index: 0
        name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_02_00.0.analog-stereo>
        driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
        flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY FLAT_VOLUME DYNAMIC_LATENCY
        state: RUNNING
        suspend cause: (none)
        priority: 9039
        volume: front-left: 46396 /  71% / -9.00 dB,   front-right: 46396 /  71% / -9.00 dB
                balance 0.00
        base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
        volume steps: 65537
        muted: no
        current latency: 531.63 ms
        max request: 168 KiB
        max rewind: 168 KiB
        monitor source: 0
        sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
        channel map: front-left,front-right
                     Stereo
        used by: 1
        linked by: 1
        configured latency: 980.00 ms; range is 2.00 .. 1999.82 ms
        card: 1 <alsa_card.pci-0000_02_00.0>
        module: 7
        properties:
                alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
                device.api = "alsa"
                device.class = "sound"
                alsa.class = "generic"
                alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
                alsa.name = "CA0132 Analog"
                alsa.id = "CA0132 Analog"
                alsa.subdevice = "0"
                alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
                alsa.device = "0"
                alsa.card = "2"
                alsa.card_name = "HDA Creative"
                alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Creative at 0xf7304000 irq 18"
                alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
                device.bus_path = "pci-0000:02:00.0"
                sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/0000:02:00.0/sound/card2"
                device.bus = "pci"
                device.vendor.id = "1102"
                device.vendor.name = "Creative Labs"
                device.product.id = "0012"
                device.product.name = "Sound Core3D [Sound Blaster Recon3D / Z-Series] (SB1570 SB Audigy Fx)"
                device.string = "front:2"
                device.buffering.buffer_size = "352768"
                device.buffering.fragment_size = "176384"
                device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
                device.profile.name = "analog-stereo"
                device.profile.description = "Analog Stereo"
                device.description = "Sound Core3D [Sound Blaster Recon3D / Z-Series] (SB1570 SB Audigy Fx) Analog Stereo"
                alsa.mixer_name = "Creative Sound Blaster Z"
                alsa.components = "HDA:11020011,11020023,00100918"
                module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
                device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
        ports:
                analog-output-lineout: Line Out (priority 9900, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
                        properties:

                analog-output-headphones: Headphones (priority 9000, latency offset 0 usec, available: yes)
                        properties:
                                device.icon_name = "audio-headphones"
        active port: <analog-output-headphones>
```

`inxi -Fx` gives this output (the Audio part):

```
Audio:     Device-1: Intel 200 Series PCH HD Audio vendor: ASUSTeK driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus ID: 00:1f.3 
           Device-2: NVIDIA GP104 High Definition Audio vendor: CardExpert driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus ID: 01:00.1 
           Device-3: Creative Labs Sound Core3D [Sound Blaster Recon3D / Z-Series] driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel 
           bus ID: 02:00.0
```

`aplay -l` gives this:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC1220 Analog [ALC1220 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 1: ALC1220 Digital [ALC1220 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: Creative [HDA Creative], device 0: CA0132 Analog [CA0132 Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: Creative [HDA Creative], device 1: CA0132 Digital [CA0132 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

On Windows everything works fine btw, so hardware is not defect. Pls help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: `pacmd` says it’s sending audio to the headphone out port of your Sound Blaster — is that what you expect?

Comment: Yes it is supposed to be the headphones. Alsa also detects them as plugged in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the card includes a DSP that needs firmware to work, and since it is unlikely that Creative has released the source code for it, it will probably be located in package `firmware-misc-nonfree`, which is in the non-free (as in "not fully open source") part of the Debian package repository.

If you cannot see the `firmware-misc-nonfree` package in your package manager, you probably did not choose to enable the non-free part of the repository during installation. The easiest way to fix it is probably to make sure the `software-properties-common` package is installed, and then run `apt-add-repository non-free` as root (using `sudo` or whatever you prefer). Then reload the package lists (e.g. `apt update`), install `firmware-misc-nonfree` and reboot.

Comment: Ok it worked, wow, thank you! You really know your stuff.